# Setting output parameter inside LINQ select

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a way to reduce the number of lines by setting the output variable inside LINQ select statement? How would you do it?

```
public void GetSomeValue(int bonusID, out decimal? maxGiving, out int? isActive)
{
    maxGiving = 0;
    isActive = 0;
    try
    {
        var con = new BonusModelDataContext();
        var a = con.Bonus
            .Where(c => c.ID == bonusID)
            .Select(c => new { maxGiving = c.maxGiving, isActive = c.isActive })
            .SingleOrDefault();
        maxGiving = a.maxGiving;
        isActive = a.isActive;

        // return iovation;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you can't do that, you can't use `out` parameters in a lambda.

But even if you could, I don't think it would be a good idea to do so, because it would make the code less readable.

There are also some suspicious practices in your code:

1. You're using `SingleOrDefault()`, but you don't check the result for `null`. If you don't want to check for `null`, use `Single()` which will throw an exception if the query returns an empty collection.
2. You're catching all exceptions. You should catch only the exceptions you know about. And you certainly shouldn't use something like `return -1`, it's much better to just let the exception bubble up and catch it somewhere up the call stack. Another option might be catching the exception, wrapping it in some more specific exception and throwing that.
3. Why are you setting the output parameters to `0` by default? They are nullable, so setting them to `null` makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 11):

svick's observations are spot on, however I suggest you go a bit further in your refactoring.

## Suggested Refactorings

### Naming

- `GetSomeValue` is not expressive. I changed it to `GetBonusDetails`, which makes more sense to me, but then again I don't know the rest of your code base - just choose a name that clearly says what the method does.
- `con` is borderline acceptable... for clarity I renamed it to `dataContext`.
- the name `a` doesn't tell us anything about what this variable contains. I renamed it to `bonus`.
- the name `isActive` is a lie. This `int` is pretending to be a `bool`, probably because it **should indeed be boolean**. I don't know for sure, since the range of possible values is not apparent in your code.

  - If it only gets assigned the values `0` and `1`, change the data type to `bool`.
  - If it can have other values, rename it to `activityStatus` or something similar.

*(from now on I will use the corrected names in my explanations and code.)*

### Exception Handling

- I changed `SingleOrDefault()` to `Single()` to avoid a possible `NullReferenceException`.
- I removed your `try-catch-statement`: swallowing an error can turn into a debugging headache in the future. I believe that in this case you should probably create a custom `BonusNotFoundException`. You would then catch this exception at a higher level and notify the user.

### Output Parameters

I agree that it would make more sense to initialize the output parameters with `null` since you made the effort of making them `Nullable`. But if you take a step back, you realize how ugly the use of `out` parameters is in this situation. **So I deleted them** and made `GetBonusDetails` return an instance of a new class designed to hold two pieces of information: `maxGiving` and `isActive`. I called it `BonusDetails`, but I'm sure you can find a much better name for it.

### LINQ Query

I rewrote your query as a `query statement` because I find the syntax less convoluted. However, using a method chain is also all right if it is more readable for you.

## End Result

### `GetBonusDetails` method

```
public BonusDetails GetBonusDetails(int bonusID)
{
    var dataContext = new BonusModelDataContext();
    var bonus = from b in dataContext.Bonus
                where b.ID == bonusID
                select new BonusDetails(b.maxGiving, b.isActive);
    return bonus.Single();
}
```

### `BonusDetails` class

```
public class BonusDetails
{
    public int MaxGiving { get; private set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; private set; }

    public BonusDetails(int maxGiving, bool isActive)
    {
        MaxGiving = maxGiving;
        IsActive = isActive;
    }
}
```

Comment: Very good advices here (but for LINQ I prefer the method chain way:P), but I recommend you to use `using` statement for _dataContext_ object in `var dataContext = new BonusModelDataContext();` (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Working on codesparkle's answer, I think this might be better still:

```
public BonusDetails GetBonusDetails(int bonusID)
{
    var dataContext = new BonusModelDataContext();
    var bonus = dataContext.Bonus.First(b =>b.ID == bonusID);
    return new BonusDetails(bonus.maxGiving, bonus.isActive);
}
```

Assuming `.ID` is unique (if not then `.Single(Func<T,bool>)` so you get the exception for more than one element). In both cases you should probably catch the internal exceptions and throw your own in its place to hide the implementation details (or specify in the method documentation that it will throw these internal exceptions, but I would think of that as bad practice).

Comment: nice one, you have my +1

Comment: I would use `Single` even if `ID` was unique, because it makes the intent clearer. And it's also safer (what if `ID` stops being unique?).